# HTML button onClick listener calling HTML form onSubmit javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a novice in web development, I have created a simple html page. The page has two buttons, **Submit** and **Display Data**. The **Submit** button is supposed to post form data to a particular page after validating the form. This button is working fine. I am facing a problem with the **Display Data** button. The button is supposed to open a separate page and there should not be any kind of form validation. The page is getting open but the form is also getting validated.

**The html page**:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var name=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
var email=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var mobile=document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].value;
var address=document.forms["myForm"]["address"].value;
var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
if (name==null || name=="")
  {
  alert("Name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }

  else if(isNaN(mobile)||mobile.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
  {
  alert("Enter numeric value")
  return false; 
  }
  else if (mobile.length != 10)
  {
  alert("Enter 10 digit mobile");
  return false;
  }
  else if (mobile.charAt(0)=="0")
  {
  alert("Mobile no should not start with 0");
  return false;
  }
  else if (address==null || address=="")
  {
  alert("Address must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h2>Employee Details Entry</h2>
<form name="myForm" action="insertDisplay.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile"><br/>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> <button onClick="location.href = 'insertDisplay.php'">Display Data</button>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

**Where am I going wrong? Why is the form validation function getting called?**

Comment: that's because you did not close the input tag for submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place 
`<button onClick="location.href = 'insertDisplay.php'">Display Data</button>` this line out of the form...

Comment: It worked, but the button is below the submit button. I want the buttons to be placed side by side..........

Answer (score 0):

give this button the type you want to behave it.

```
<button type="button" onClick="location.href = 'insertDisplay.php'">Display Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the values out of the form, or you can use, `<input type="button"/>` tag. It will not submit your form and will work as you intended.

```
<input type="button" value="display data" onClick="location.href = 'a.php'">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you also want your datas to be passed to your PHP file after clicking your button ?
If you push the  out of the form will not be sended and you'll have no datas.
In fact, you want both buttons to submit your form, but only the first one should validate it ?

If this is it you can do this :

```
<form name="myForm" action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile"><br/>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="typesubmit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" />
<input type="submit" name="typesubmit" value="Display Data" />
</form>
```

You'll be abled on your insert.php file to make difference between display and submit by checking $_POST['typesubmit'] value.

And if you want your "display" button to post your form on another php file, you can do this :

```
<form name="myForm" action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile"><br/>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" />
<input type="submit" value="Display Data" onclick="document.myForm.action='display.php';" />
</form>
```